# UDP server for receiving packets from two ports simultaneously with python asyncio

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make a UDP server that receives packets from two ports.

You may imagine a call center which is recording metadata of each call and voices of it.

The metadata consists of f'START_CALL_{call_id}', f'CELL_END_{call_id}', which start and end loop, and speech does of several f'SPEECH_{call_id}_{idx}'.

So, the packets' arrival seems like below. (The UDP server receives metadata from localhost:3001, and vocices from localhost:3002.)

| 3001 | 'START_CALL_001' |  |  | 'END_CALL_001' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3002 |  | 'SPEECH 001_01' | 'SPEECH 001_02' |  |

I think the server needs both packets at once as metadata says when the call started and ended.

At this point, I tried to use high-level udp endpoints package, aioudp from (https://gist.github.com/vxgmichel/e47bff34b68adb3cf6bd4845c4bed448)
with asyncio packages for receiving both packets like

```
import asyncio
import aioudp
    
local_ip = '0.0.0.0'
metadata_port = 3001
speech_port = 3002
buffer_size = 1024

async def process():
    # set both endpoints
    meta_ep = await aioudp.open_local_endpoint(local_ip, metadata_port)
    spch_ep = await aioudp.open_local_endpoint(local_ip, speech_port)
    while True:
        # receive packets, which causes problems
        metadata, addr = await meta_ep.receive()
        speech, _ = await meta_ep.receive()
        print(f'metadata_rcvd:{metadata}')
        print(f'speech_rcvd:{speech}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(process())
```

But at this point, I noticed that receiving speech packets gets delayed and lost (such as START->SPEECH_001_02->END) when I try to get it with metadata, and vice versa.

So I tried to use the low-level example such as,

```
import asyncio

local_ip = '0.0.0.0'
metadata_port = 3001
speech_port = 3002
buffer_size = 1024

class Protocol(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def connectoin_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        print(data)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # set tasks for creating endpoints
    Tm = asyncio.Task(loop.create_datagram_endpoint(Protocol, local_addr=(local_ip, 3001)))
    Ts = asyncio.Task(loop.create_datagram_endpoint(Protocol, local_addr=(local_ip, 3002)))
    trans_meta, port_meta = loop.run_until_complete(Tm)
    trans_spch, port_spch = loop.run_until_complete(Ts)
    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It seemingly works well for receiving both packets at same time, but I couldn't understand the principles of receiving data packets neither deal with those.

I would ask helps for understanding the reason why those packets are delayed and looking sequential, and how can I deal with the data packets from asyncio.DatagramProtocol.